# images not displaying whenever wrapped in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://adamginther.com

If you click on the Canucks image(this third icon underneath "information architecture and usability") no image is displaying beside the text even though an image is entered via HTML. This image displays unless wrapped within a div. It is required that I have a div wrapped around it as it is supposed to be a slideshow.

Is there any way to fix this, or is there anyway to build a slideshow that does not require a div?

HTML

```
<div id="canucksdisplay">
        <p>
            <button class="closeButton">X</button>
        <br>
        <br><class id="blueText">You are viewing: Canucks Usability Tests</class><br>Role: Usability Testing<br><br>The Vancouver Canucks is one of Canada's biggest sports teams, with a very strong and avid community. A lot of their community use their website to interact with each other about recent trades, rumours, and debates. 
        <br>
        <br>
        I was tasked with testing the usablity of Canucks.NHL.com's community features and social features. This involved in analyzing Canucks' target user and thinking of the potential downfalls the user may have while navigating the website and recording a test participant doing so. These tests ended up being successful in pointing out the uncovered flaws.</p>
        <div id="slideshowContainer">
            <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="images/work/canucks1.png">
        <img src="images/work/canucks2.png">
        <img src="images/work/canucks3.png">
    </div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#displays div {
    background-image: url(../images/linedpaper.png);
    border: 1px dashed black;
    display: none;
    height: 675px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#displays div p {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
    height: 550px;
    left: 0 !important;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
#displays div img {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    margin: 20px 0 0 10%;

}
#displayedwork {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
#displayedwork img {
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 449px;
}
```

jQuery

```
    //slideshow
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
    pause: 1,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next'

    });
});
    });
```

Comment: It seems to be showing now.

Comment: which OS/browser are you using? This has not worked for me on any browser on my Mac and it did not work on my iPhone.

Comment: It would be better if you posted your HTML and JS here, rather than linking to an external site, and stripped it down to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. I don't see a Canucks image, the third icon says "Contact information".

Comment: Found it under "Information Architecture & Usability", not "Development".

Comment: yes. Sorry about that, I have posted the corresponding code.

Comment: When I hover over the image elements in the DOM, it says "0 x 0 pixels (Natural: 600 x 600 pixels)". I'm not sure where that 0x0 is coming from.

Comment: I think it's related to `#displays div { display: none; }` in your CSS. You probably want `#displays > div` so it only applies to the immediate children, not all nested DIVs.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it: Do you want to show 1 image or more than 1 image (n images) in a slideshow besides the text?

Comment: the image now displays. Thank you very much, I spent the last 8 hours with no progress and this works.

Answer (score 0):

Currently when you are adding the div its `display is being set to`none` some how.

So when you are adding the `div` set its display to 'inline' or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JS error in the console "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined**" which could possibly be the reason for JS not working as expected in the page.

$.browser was removed from jQuery version 1.9. And I see you are using jQuery version - 1.10.0. If you still need it, it is available as plugin(https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin).